# How do I add a Rigid body and a box collider component to a Texture2D?

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I am making a snake game. I'm basing it on a basic tutorial game, which does no collision detection, wall checking or different levels.

All snake head, piece, food, even the background is made of `Texture2D`. I want the head of the snake to detects 2D collisions with them, but `Rect.contains` isn't working. I'd prefer to detect collisions by `onTriggerEnter()` for which I need to add `BoxCollider` to my `snakeHead`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to check if two rectangles collide?

Comment: no, not at all. I am asking can we add physics2D components to the Texture2D object? or If something else that I can do for it?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add [`BoxCollider2D`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-BoxCollider2D.html)?  You have an entity, you have a texture attached to it, and you know the other thing you need to add.  Why not add it?

Comment: How do you draw your Texture2D? If you use sprites then it's an object which ALSO can have a BoxCollider component.

Comment: Well, What are you people thinking?? Well, the answer I was trying to figure out was indeed because of my unfamiliarity with Unity.
I was making Texture with GUI.DrawTexture in OnGUI() Method.
Now the problem has been solved. As I didn't had any mentor so just learnt things by just posting stuff and getting answers thanks allot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get onTriggerEnter events, you need to set the **Is Trigger** flag to true.

[image: isTrigger flag]

Comment: @gamenewdev I have a feeling that did not answer your question..

Comment: Yeah U have the right feeling :(

Comment: @gamenewdev, rather than insincerely thanking people who try to answer based on the limited information available from you, you should improve your question to allow better answers to be posted.  You might start by explaining _why_ this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Ok @SethBattin I'll definitely try next time. I am not a native English speaker, also I am totally a bigginer in unity. That's why I was unable to tell you what I am seeking.

Comment: The thing is that I am not making anything from Unity's Editor in my case, so I can not check ontrigger checkbox from Editor. I made all my textures through scripts. Thanks to all the moderators. who just edit my question without even thinking, what I am saying. They just edit and the whole context of question changes.

Comment: You wouldn't be adding the box collider etc to a texture2d... You'd be adding it to a GameObject that has a texture2d... You are creating a snake game that grows when you eat food? When your snake eats good you procedurally create a new body node and you want to know how to add a collider and rigidbody to that?? Is that what your actual question is?

Answer (score 3):

There should be an object that holds your texture and to that object you could add a collider.

Answer (score 1):

If your game is 2D, you can use Rigidbody2D and BoxCollider2D. It will give you a performance boost, and will ignore Z position differences.

To get `OnTriggerEnter` or `OnTriggerEnter2D`, you need to check the *"Is Trigger"* checkbox in collider settings. Please note that doing so will remove your ability to make rigidbody respond collisions.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already added "2D collisions", then you can't add "BoxCollider" because it is a 3D object. You have to add the components of the same type. Meaning, if you are going to use the 3D object like "BoxCollider", then you have to add a 3D collision not 2D collision. That means you have to add "Shpare collider" instead of 2D collider.